# how to implement verilog divisible by 6?

Tags: verilog

I wanna create divisible by 6 module in verilog using divisible by 2 module and divisible by 3 module, I grasped the idea, but maybe my verilog grammar is wrong.

the module structure i want to implement is below,

```
module Divisible_6(input [3:0] a, output out);
```

using

```
module Divisible_2(
input [3:0] a,
output out
);

module Divisible_3(
input [3:0] a,
output out
);
```

and if input is 6(0110), then both divisible_2 and divisible_3 output 1,

and both 1 goes in to the AND gate, then came out with 1.

1 = true, 0 = false.

how can I implement the idea in verilog language?

and help is appreciated, thanks.

input: 1~15

Answer (score 1):

Since I understand question a little bit different than @Morgan, I'd rather try this code:

```
module Divisible_6(
  input [3:0] a,    
  output out
);

  wire out_1, out_2;

  assign out = out_1 & out_2;

  Divisible_2(
    .a  (a),
    .out(out_1)
  );

  Divisible_3(
    .a  (a),
    .out(out_2)
  );

endmodule
```

I assume that both `Divisible_2` and `Divisible_3` take 4-bit input and return boolean value (divisible (1) or not (0)).

Answer (score 0):

You need `divisible by 6` design, which can only be obtained, if your input is both `divisible by 2` and `divisible by 3`.

Hence you can use both modules, like the following code.

```
// Defining the nets
logic out1, out2;

// Continuous Assignment
assign out = out1 & out2;

// Instantiation of 2 modules with instance name d1 & d2
divisible_2 d1 (a, out1);
divisible_3 d2 (a, out2);
```